# Delete routing profile in Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-connect

Does anybody know how to remove the routing profile from amazon connect?
There are only create, read, and partial update operations in the Amazon documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to remove a routing profile in Amazon Connect once it has been created.  As you pointed out in your question, there are no options to do this in the console and there is also no delete function in the public API (see doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html))

The name attribute of the routing profile is mutable though, so you could rename and reconfigure it to a future use if your original profile was no longer relevant or needed.